# Deploy web service on Tomcat with OpenEJB

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, openejb

I need to deploy web service on Tomcat with installed OpenEJB.
I compiled simple Hello service that just prints "Hello" with JAX-WS and tried to deploy on tomcat, but got errors while deployment :
ERROR - Error deploying CXF webservice for servlet helloservice.endpoint.Hello
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find servlet helloservice in web application context /helloservice

Please, help what is done wrong here.
Is tomcat + openejb is sufficient for web service deployment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please, help what is done wrong here.
>   Is tomcat + openejb is sufficient for
>   web service deployment?

A servlet/JSP engine is sufficient for web development.  You don't need OpenEJB for that.

"Service" is a loaded term.  Do you mean "SOAP web service"?  Or "EJB stateless session bean"?

Check your web.xml.  Sounds like you failed to declare a servlet named helloservice.  It ought to look like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>helloservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.your.package.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>helloservlet</servlet-name> <!-- names must match -->
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used it with some changes.
For web services needs to use 
<servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
in servlet element and 
<url-pattern>/helloservice</url-pattern>
in servlet-mapping element.
Also need to add sun-jaxws.xml that contains smth like :

<endpoint name='helloservice'
  implementation='helloservice.endpoint.Hello'
  url-pattern='/helloservice' />

where helloservice.endpoint.Hello is an implementation of 'helloservice' web service

Answer (score 3):

For others who might be looking to do web services with Tomcat/OpenEJB, here's a simple example that uses an transactional EJB web service to add/list/delete records with JPA:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openejb/tags/openejb-3.1.2/examples/webapps/moviefun/

The example also includes a Perl SOAP::Lite client that can read/write to the web service.

Comment: Please modify the answer as the provided link works no more.